# Spectrometer design

Tags: optics

I am looking to design a compact spectrometer based on using one single concave grating as both the dispersive optic and the imaging optic. I am investigating these gratings:

```
https://www.edmundoptics.com/f/zeiss-concave-diffraction-gratings/39624/
```

I require a center wavelength of 1700nm (with min = 1680nm, max = 1720nm). Does anyone see a reason why using these UV wavelength optimised mirrors would not for for Infrared wavelengths? I have a design that assumes looking at the 2nd order but I do not know what diffraction efficiency I will get at these wavelengths.

Thanks,

Jordan.

Comment: Maybe this is better suited for engineering SE?

Comment: If they work, then cost would be the reason. Just look at the mirror spectra of send Edmund an email.

Comment: You should ask for a datasheet with performance (loss, resolution, etc.) in the IR range. Then see if you're happy with the numbers for your application.

Comment: I already did and I’m waiting a response. But I have more faith in physicists and engineering than I do talking to a middle man sales rep. That’s why I came here for a better answer than the supplier.